# Bash scripting problem on echo -ing the current working directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash 

#clear screen
clear 

# Ask for name of directory to create
echo "Please enter a directory name"
echo "that you wish to create"
read dir1

# create directory
mkdir $dir1

# change to the newly created directory
cd $dir1

# Tell user where he/she is
echo "This directory is called 'pwd'"


# create some files
touch file1 file2 file3


# put in some content 
echo "This is $dir1/file1" > file1
echo "This is $dir1/file2" > file2
echo "This is $dir1/file3" > file3



# announce file names
echo "The files in $dir1 are: "
ls -hl

# show the contents  of the files
echo "The content of the files are: "
cat file1
cat file2
cat file3


echo "Goodbye"
```

The line with echo "This directory is called 'pwd'" refuses to give the current working directory as expected. Please help me resolve this issue, I am currently learning BASH SHELL SCRIPTING

Comment: Jacob please check it again, and please who nailed the -1 on my question is it that bad?

Comment: Just a small hint - before creating a new dir via 'mkdir' it would be safer to check if that folder already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
echo "This directory is called $(pwd)"
```

What you are trying to do is called *command substitution*. 
This used to be done using backticks (`` ` ` ``), but the currently recommended way is using `$()`.

You can find a detailed explanation [in this wiki page.](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Command_substitution)

Comment: Thanks wayne_yux , the 411 on the 'backticks' helped me see the error in my interpretation of the source code

Answer (score 2):

To get the current working directory as a *variable*:

```
echo $PWD
```

(capitals), or use the *command*

```
pwd
```

Then, using the *variable*, the line should be:

```
echo "This directory is called '$PWD'"
```

Output:

```
This directory is called /home/jacob
```